# net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED on dynamic script load

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load a script (from the same origin!) during run time (on button click), but for a strange reason I get in the console the error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

The example is in this link: https://www.crazygao.com/ef4/tst.htm

By clicking the text area, a call is initialized to load a form - this one though using the same dynamic script loading, for some strange reason succeed.
When clicking on the "+" to add item inside the combo box, the error will be triggered - the requested script will fail to load.

Note the way I am doing the calls:

```
// Call to external function in a script:
_.Run=function(p) {
    if(_.xT(p)=="S") p={f:p}; // If the call is string, it will convert it to function name
    if(!window[p.f]) { // If the function not exists in global scope, need to look for the JS file to request it.
        _.xR("/"+p.x||p.f,function() { _.Run(p); }); // Dynamic loader
    }
    else { window[p.f](p.v); } // Run the function
}

// Short hand for loading script on runtime:
_.xR=function(p,f,a) {
    var r=_.xM("script"); // I am creating new <script> tag
    _.xW(r,"charset","UTF-8"); // I set attribute "charset" to "UTF-8"
    r.src=p; // I set the source
    // "a" is not relevant for here - I cut it off
    document.head.appendChild(r); // I append to document head
}

// Short hand for creating new element and appending it to the DOM
_.xM=function(t,i,r,s,c,u) {
    t=document.createElement(t);
    if(t.nodeName=="IMG") t.ondragstart=function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }
    if(i) t.id=i;
    if(r) _.xI(r).insertBefore(t,u);
    /* Unnecessary data I cut off */
    return t;
}

// Short hand for getting element by ID
_.xI=function(e,c) {
    if(_.xT(e)=="S") e=document.getElementById(e); return (e||c)?e:document.body;
}

// Short hand for getting type of variable
_.xT=function(e) {
    if(e instanceof Array) return "A";
    if(e instanceof ML) return "L";
    if(e instanceof Date) return "D";
    if(e instanceof FF) return "F";
    if(e instanceof _.P) return "P";
    if(e instanceof _.C) return "C";
    if(e instanceof Image) return "I";
    if(typeof e==="number"&&!isNaN(e)) return "N";
    if(typeof e==="string") return "S";
    if(typeof e==="boolean") return "B";
    if(typeof e==="function") return "Q";
    return e?"O":null;
}

// Short hand for setting or removing attribute
_.xW=function(c,n,v,s) {
    return s?_.xW(c,n,_.xW(c,n,"~")?0:v):c[(v?(v=="~"?"get":"set"):"remove")+"Attribute"](n,v);
}
```

I don't believe I have any mistake in the "shortcuts", as they are working for other scripts that been loaded (can see in the example link).

In the server nothing is blocking, as the same directory is read by the same script and succeed to download (in the example link: ML.js succeed, Lang.js fail)

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: The problem is, you're trying to go to `http://ef4/whatever` which tends to make me believe that the issue lies with a simple typo. Make sure when specifying a call to a server, that you prepend the string with `/` to force it to go to the same server.

Comment: The variable _.rot = "/ef4" (so it contains the "/") unless happened somewhere that it produces "//" - is this can cause this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: Seems that the root cause of the problem is not missing "/", but repeating preceding "/" causing "https:////ef4/Lang.js" -> The browser perhaps treat this as "https://ef4/Lang.js" - hence a mistake...

Problem Solved:)